# Sails.js (0.10.5) file upload with custom middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have a sails.js app that I am now maintaining but was written by a different developer. I am not very proficient with sails and having difficulty with implementing a file-upload.

In general, I understand that sails handles file upload with skipper and that the upload API is available through skipper. Further more, I managed to create a new bare-bone application, and in it I am able to do the file upload following the examples available in the documentation.

In my full application though, there are some customizations in the http configuration. In my controller, `req.file` is `undefined` (as is `files`).

Also, comparing the config/http.js of the full and test apps the structure is different. AFAIK, both real and test apps are 0.10.5 (but on my computer, global sails is 0.12.x though in the new app folder I see sails 0.10.5 and I did run the script for creating it from 0.10.5 folder).

From reading a little, it seems either I have something not configured correctly or that my overrides are omitting skipper from the middleware chain. This could also be an issue with incompatible config file as possibly, the initial version of my real app was developed in earlier versions of sails.

Following is the content of config/http.js in my full app:

```
/**
 * Configure advanced options for the Express server inside of Sails.
 */
module.exports.http = {
    bodyParser: function() {
        return require('body-parser')({limit: '900mb'});
    },
    customMiddleware: function(app) {

        var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
        var expressJwt = require('../libs/express-jwt');
        var experssJwtConfig = require('./jwt.js').jwt;

        app.use(function(req, res, next) {
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            next();
        });

        app.use('/api', expressJwt({secret: experssJwtConfig.secret}));

        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());


        if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') {
            // just for local/development - serve static files
            var express = require('express');
            app.use('/custom1', express.static('D:/Temp/custom1/'));
            app.use('', express.static(process.cwd() + '/assets/'));
        }

    }
};

/**
 * HTTP Flat-File Cache
 */
module.exports.cache = {
    // The number of seconds to cache files being served from disk
    // (only works in production mode)
    maxAge: 31557600000
};
```

Anything comes to mind? Is there a way to debug and see why I don't have the `file` function within the request object? Maybe I should somehow update/upgrade the configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out to be a simple matter - sails (as of version around 10) uses skipper as the body parser. Skipper includes the required functionality for uploading files. In the above, specifying `bodyParser` overrides this and hence, I am not getting the `file` function and other built-in skipper functionality.

Now I have to either go back to using skipper (which will require some thorough testing to make sure nothing breaks) or include additional middleware to facilitate file upload... (any comments on that?)

Comment: Yes, having custom middleware as body parser will override not only your skipper configuration, but all of the other middleware sails uses internally. I suggest you keep the sails defaults since they are coupled with the app and slowly re-do the whole app leaving sails out as a dependency.

Comment: @drinchev - thanks for the comment. I am not sure I am following you. What do you mean in "redoing the app and leaving sails out"? You suggest to stop using it?

Comment: Another, general question: in sails.js - if I am using skipper should I worry about including `app.use(bodyParser.json());` and `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());` in custom middleware or is that redundant and can be omitted?